# Hosting non web based application in IIS 7

Tags: c#, iis, windows-services, hosting, iis-7.5

I have heard that you can host non-web based applications in IIS7 similar to windows services. Basically I want a C# app that is just a process running all the time to perform a specific function. I want to create a process that connects to the database at an interval and does some work.

I would like this whole app to be housed inside IIS. Is this possible? Can you provide me with links and resources to get me started?

Comment: Why do you need IIS? Why can't it just be a Windows Service?

Comment: I don't necessarily NEED IIS. Just trying to branch out a little. Plus IIS offers a lot of nice things out of the box. For one, it's MUCH easier to deploy to on a large scale. You don't need to stop services to deploy.

Answer (score 1):

[WCF services](https://web.archive.org/web/20120808064558/http://msdn.microsoft.com:80/en-US/netframework/aa663324.aspx) can be hosted in IIS. Abstractly, think of them as webservices. Really much more, than that, but it gives you the gist. More information:

[How to: Host a WCF Service in IIS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wcf/feature-details/how-to-host-a-wcf-service-in-iis)
[Why we use wcf rather than web services](https://web.archive.org/web/20101217060835/http://keithelder.net/blog/archive/2008/10/17/WCF-vs-ASMX-WebServices.aspx)
[How To: Hosting a WCF Service in IIS](https://web.archive.org/web/20160223064435/http://blogs.msdn.com:80/b/trobbins/archive/2006/11/27/how-to-hosting-a-wcf-service-in-iis.aspx)

Comment: I know what WCF is...I know how to host it in IIS...that was not my question. IF you read my question i'm looking to host other applications similar to WINDOWS services in IIS.

Comment: sorry, didn't mean to imply otherwise. As for your question, I've used WCF for similar services. And used the WF integration to provide the trigger to fire off the service.

Comment: similar in that my process would kick off every hour, scan a folder for new files, update the database.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at AppFabric it's Microsofts Application Server

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windowsserver/ee695849.aspx
http://www.hanselman.com/blog/InstallingConfiguringAndUsingWindowsServerAppFabricAndTheVelocityMemoryCacheIn10Minutes.aspx

Comment: So you don't want to host an app in IIS?